# remove fortigate account from fortinet router

Tags: router, fortigate

i have fortigate 60E that was register on computing company ,
now this company has been closed and already passed more then 3 years ,
im trying to unregister the fortiget its ask for the password of the
email of the computing company that there is not way to contact them
any suggestion how to remove that account from the fortigate?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do this by yourself.

Contact Fortinet support and explain the situation, they will work with you.